# observer concept in the reactive programming shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shinyapps, observers

I wonder if anybody can explain the following concepts about the observer (taken from [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/reactivity-objects.html)) in the simplest way possible.? Why is every time that x changes the number of times is printed increases?

[image]

```
x <- reactiveVal(1)
y <- observe({
  x()
  observe(print(x()))
})

#> [1] 1
x(2)
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 2
x(3)
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 3
```

Comment: The example is misleading. If you start by `x(10)`it will be printed twice too. The number of prints has nothing to do with the value of `x`.

Comment: It's hard to explain better than the sentence at the bottom. Maybe someone who speaks English better than me could provide a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it's not easy for me to explain better than the last given sentence. Each time `x()` changes, a *new* nested observer is created. The first one performs `print(x)`, the second one as well, etc. Each one prints the value of `x`.

The code below shows that there are three nested observers at the end, but there's another difficulty, namely understanding `local()`.

```r
library(shiny)
reactiveConsole(TRUE)

x <- reactiveVal(1)
i <- 0
observe({
  x()
  i <<- i + 1
  local({
    j <- i
    observe({
      x()
      print(paste("Hello I am the nested observer", j))
    })
  })
})
# [1] "Hello I am the nested observer 1"
# > x(12)
# [1] "Hello I am the nested observer 1"
# [1] "Hello I am the nested observer 2"
# > x(16)
# [1] "Hello I am the nested observer 1"
# [1] "Hello I am the nested observer 2"
# [1] "Hello I am the nested observer 3"
```

Think about this one too:

```r
x <- reactiveVal(1)
observe({
  x()
  local({
    y <- x()
    observe({
      x()
      print(y)
    })
  })
})
# [1] 1
# > x(5)
# [1] 1
# [1] 5
# > x(9)
# [1] 1
# [1] 5
# [1] 9
```

---

This other example is instructive as well:

```
x <- reactiveVal(10)
observe({
  x()
  observe({
    req(x() >= 3)
    print(x())
  })
})
# [1] 10
# > x(2) # a new nested observer is created but it doesn't react because 2 < 3
# > x(1) # a new nested observer is created but it doesn't react because 1 < 3
# > x(4) # a new nested observer is created and it reacts because 4 >= 3
# [1] 4
# [1] 4
# [1] 4
# [1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the example since it is immediately followed by:

> As a general rule, you should only ever create observers or outputs at
> the top-level of your server function. If you find yourself trying to
> nest them or create an observer inside an output, sit down and sketch
> out the reactive graph that you’re trying to create — there’s almost
> certainly a better approach.

That said, the point is that the observer is created regardless of if or what it is assigned to.  Each time `x` changes, the statement inside of `y` runs again. That statement creates a NEW unique observer that prints x. It does not overwrite the previously created observer.  By changing `x` 3 times, you've created 3 unique printing observers.