# In R Shiny, why does embedding 'observeEvent' in for loops fail while it works with lapply?

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, event-handling, lapply

I have noticed that the `for` and `lapply` loops behave differently when they contain one or several `observeEvent`. In my case, this led to issues when defining several action buttons: what happened is that while the `lapply` loop correctly linked each button to its action, the `for` loop assigned all the actions to the last button, which is incorrect.

Why do these functions work differently and why does the `for` one fail?

Here is a small working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button1", "1"),
  actionButton("button2", "2"),
  actionButton("button3", "3")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # The for loop fails
  for(i in seq_len(3)) {
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("button", i)]], {
      print(paste0("for: ", i))
    })
  }

  # the lapply function works
  lapply(seq_len(3), function(i) {
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("button", i)]], {
      print(paste0("lapply: ", i))
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52911030/16730940 <- see this existing answer for an  explanation

Comment: If you want to use a loop, you have to use `local()`.

Comment: Yes that answers my question, thank you two

Comment: See also <https://stackoverflow.com/a/73832322/1100107>.